# Add rows based on column index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has the following columns:

```
 id     index1    index2    value
 DivA     1         4        3
 DivA     3         6        4
 DivB     1         3        5
 DivB     5         7        3
```

On another dataframe I have the following:

```
 id      index
DivA       1
DivA       2
      ...
DivA       10
DivB       1
      ...
```

final result:
df2:

```
 id      index    value
DivA       1        3
DivA       2       nan (because no value in df1)
DivA       3        4
DivA       4        3
      ...
DivA       10       nan (because no value in df1)
DivB       1        5
      ...
```

I'm wondering if I can add a new column 'value' to the second df in a way that 'index1' and 'index2'
are combined and that 'value' in the second df can have 'nan' if there is no values in the first dataframe 'value' ?

Thank you for help !

Comment: check with df.melt('id')

Comment: it puts the three columns into one, what I'm looking for is that I transform the 'index1' and 'index2' into 'index' where the missing values in the two columns have a nan, any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  #pd.melt first dataframe
    df3=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id','value'], value_vars=['index1', 'index2'], value_name='index').drop(columns=['variable'])

#pd.concat second dataframe to the pd.met result, sort-values and drop duplicates in index 
(pd.concat([df3, df1], ignore_index=True).sort_values(by=['id','index'])).drop_duplicates(subset=['index'],keep='first')



     id  value  index
0   DivA    3.0      1
9   DivA    NaN      2
1   DivA    4.0      3
4   DivA    3.0      4
5   DivA    4.0      6
10  DivA    NaN     10
3   DivB    3.0      5
7   DivB    3.0      7
```

Comment: It works, I found out that pd.melt can very usefull in a lot of tasks but need a bit of time to understand the concept, thank you !